# Jump to next bootstrap jumbotron while browser scrolls

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my project, i have some  jumbotron (tweeter bootstrap v3) elements. What i want is if user scroll the page, next jumbotron will jump in the screen. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean `next jumbotron will jump in the screen`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage
or
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html (similar)